# How to make a placebo drink taste convincing?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, alcohols

I'm trying to make a placebo alcoholic drink - something strong (cognac, whiskey or vodka). Is it possible to make a drink containing absolutely no alcohol *taste* like it's got 30 or 40% alcohol? What can I add to give it that "kick"?

Comment: Genuinely interested if there might be a combination of chemicals out there safe for human consumption that would mimic the taste of spirits. I doubt I'll get my answer from cooking websites. My intention is not finding the recipie for the perfect mocktail; I'm conducting a small experiment. I have limited knowledge on chemistry which is why I'm here - please help! It's for a good cause.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question. The perception of what makes a typical cognac, brandy or whisky definitely has a scientific background. The fingerprint of  volatile compounds has been examined by GC/MS for [brandy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/labs/articles/19323737/), [cognac (brandy)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1012365629636) and [whisky](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17027810)

Comment: This is a tough one. Most of the things I can think of would have some combination of still being intoxicating, tasting bad, and giving you serious liver damage.